# Applying border-radius without applying it to box-shadow

Tags: html, css

Is there anyway to apply a border radius to a div, but without applying the same "roundness" to the box shadow? I'm using box-shadow without a blur to effectively create two borders for a div, but the light blue box-shadow needs to be squared off.

Thanks!

Comment: If you need to create two borders see the following article, no need to reinvent the wheel: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/

Comment: I wasn't just looking for how to add two borders, I'm looking specifically for box-shadow use because of an additional feature that somebody else on down the line will be using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `outline` CSS property.<sup>[(Outline works in all browsers, except IE7 and below.)](http://caniuse.com/outline)</sup>

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}

.box {
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xN4pF/

---

Or you can nest a `<div>` within another.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="shadow">
  <div class="round"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}

.shadow {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
}
.round {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DzCK9/1/

Comment: While these work well for adding two borders, I specifically was looking for use with the box-shadow because the team I'm working with is going to be adding something else, basically a type of animation involving the box-shadow. These options also leave a little white area where the inner border is rounded. Any way to get around that?
Thanks!